# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/StyleRes.class

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/StyleRes.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 21.555 secs

```
gradle.build:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cybussolutions.wikki.afripay"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    } //Update code formatting
```

Can anyone have answer for it. it is giving compilation error. Error log is posted along with gradle file. ANyone can share link, i didnt found sol for it on net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** Your Project .

Comment: stackoverflow dosent allow me to as my reutaion is less then 15 :(